# Header incorrect in LaTeX

Tags: header-footer

My even page header is coming like

> 10CHAPTER 3. TEMPORAL

where `10` is page number and chapter is `3` and `3` is the name of the chapter.
Whereas odd page header is fine as it displays section number followed by section name on the left side and page number on the right side.

I want same format for the even pages too. Which package should I use?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As far as I can tell this behaviour is not really standard, so it would be really handy to show us a short code example of how you got there, this is best done in an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). A solution will heavily depend on the document class used as well as some other packages in action. The KOMA classes have good facilities for headers and footers, and then there are `fancyhdr` and friends.